# Displaying Layer Group in QGIS Server with WFS?

Tags: qgis, wfs

I want to display layers with QGIS server, but the group layer doesn't get displayed, instead I get a bad request response from the server:

The request:

> http://myserver/cgi-bin/91589/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=94043_CADASTRE&SRSNAME=EPSG:2154&OUTPUTFORMAT=GeoJSON

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.2.0">
  <ServiceException code="RequestNotWellFormed">
    TypeName '94043_CADASTRE' unknown
  </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Server Response

[image]
And here is a peek at the layer section in QGIS:

[image]
Layers

Comment: Group layers do not make sense with WFS because the layers which belong to the group may have different schemas. You must fetch the layers one be one.

Comment: @user30184 Okay, but when i get them out of the group, i can't even see them in the GetCapabilities response with both WFS and WMS. ??! do you have any idea why is that. All i get is bad request response and the "typename is unknown"

Comment: If you do not see some layer in WFS GetCapabilities then the administrator of the service perhaps does not want to publish it through WFS. But you may suffer from some other issue as well. BTW. your screen capture shows layer 91326_CADASTRE but in the text you try to read 94043 but I guess that's not important and all, perhaps municipalities, behave in a similar way.

Comment: You may not see the layers with a WMS GetMap request if the layers have scale layering.

Answer (score 2):

Layer groups are a feature of the WMS service and have no meaning in the WFS service.

Comment: Even in WMS, The layers grouped in "91326_CADASTRE" ( in the image above), don't show in the  response of GetCapabilities( or GetFeature). 
I'm afraid it's a setting in the project file.

Comment: Yes that is one of the reasons to use a layer group